# Unable to insert nested record in postgres

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

i had managed to create tables in postgres but encountered issues when trying to insert values.

```
comands = (
CREATE TYPE student AS ( 
   name TEXT,
   id  INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE studentclass( 
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (date, time), 
    class student
)
)
And in psycog2

command = (
INSERT INTO studentclass (date, time, student) VALUES (%s,%s, ROW(%s,%s)::student)
)


student_rec = ("John", 1)
record_to_insert = ("2020-05-21", "2020-05-21 08:10:00", student_rec)
cursor.execute(commands, record_to_insert)
```

When executed, the errors are the incorrect argument and if i tried to hard coded the student value inside the INSERT statement, it will inform me about the unrecognized column for student.

Please advise.

Comment: Without knowing Python, I'd assume that the whole `student_rec` will be supplied as a single `%s`. Make `record_to_insert` have 4 members.

Comment: Doesn't this work: `record_to_insert = ("2020-05-21", "2020-05-21 08:10:00", "John", 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is the column name is `class` not `student`. Second is `psycopg2` does `tuple` adaption as [composite type](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple)

So you can do:

```
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO studentclass (date, time, class) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
student_rec = ("John", 1)
record_to_insert = ("2020-05-21", "2020-05-21 08:10:00", student_rec)
cur.execute(insert_sql, record_to_insert)
con.commit()

select * from studentclass ;
    date    |          time           |  class   
------------+-------------------------+----------
 05/21/2020 | 05/21/2020 08:10:00 PDT | (John,1)
```

Comment: will appreciate if you can help on this as well. thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64922416/insertion-of-nested-array-of-custom-in-table-for-postgres