# insertion of nested array of custom in table for postgres

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

```
command = (

CREATE TYPE belongings AS (
   item TEXT,
   quantity INTEGER
)

CREATE TYPE student AS ( 
   name TEXT,
   id  INTEGER,
   bag belongings[]
)

CREATE TABLE studentclass( 
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (date, time), 
    class student
)
)
```

Can i ask how to do insert for this in postgres psycog2? thank you.

When i put the insert as
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO studentclass (date, time, class) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"

error output is
DETAIL:  Cannot cast type text[] to belongings[] in column

I don't think i just cast it with "::belongings[]" in the INSERT statement as it is a nested.

My earlier asked question for a simpler table.

[Unable to insert nested record in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897680/unable-to-insert-nested-record-in-postgres/64900260#64900260)

Comment: It would be much better if you used a properly normalized model. Object types are nice as an academic concept, but usually don't pay off in real world data models. Especially when combined with de-normalizing approaches like arrays.

Comment: Second this.  Just create tables instead of types. You are adding a layer of complexity with no benefit. You are going to have to do the 'joins' to the nested tables at some point anyway.

Comment: In addition to above why are using both DATE and TIMESTAMPTZ. Timestamptz contains both date and time. Also I suggest as data names both date and time are poor choices. Both are SQL reserved words and Date a Postgres reserved word. Now while you can get away with this Postgres could decide enforce SQL definitions/requirements and thereby cause you column names to become invalid.